# Grouping and merging with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need some help with this.

I´ve to transform this dataframe without duplicates in column "name"

you can see that I have duplicates in column "name" ex:John , Joan

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['John','John','Joan','Joan','Juan'], 
                   'time':[20,10,11,18, 15], 
                   'amount':[100, 400, 200, 100, 300]})
df0

    name    time    amount
0   John    20  100
1   John    10  400
2   Joan    11  200
3   Joan    18  100
4   Juan    15  300
```

I need to transform this, grouping the dataframe in this way, I don´t know if is the right way.

```
dfend0 = df0.groupby('name').agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
dfend0

             time   amount
name        
Joan    [11, 18]    [200, 100]
John    [20, 10]    [100, 400]
Juan    [15]        [300]
```

The column "name" is now the index, this isn´t the behavior I was looking for

```
 list(dfend0.columns.values)

    ['time', 'amount']
```

#Now I need to merge with other dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name' : ['John' ,'Joan', 'Juan'],
    'address' : ['streetA','streetB','streetC'],
    'age' : [30,40,50]
})
df1

    name    address age
0   John    streetA 30
1   Joan    streetB 40
2   Juan    streetC 50

ender = df1.merge(df0)
ender

    name    address age time amount
0   John    streetA 30  20  100
1   John    streetA 30  10  400
2   Joan    streetB 40  11  200
3   Joan    streetB 40  18  100
4   Juan    streetC 50  15  300
```

This is not what I´m looking for, this example would be more accurate:

```
    name    address age time    amount
0   John    streetA 30  20,10   100,400
1   Joan    streetB 40  11,18   200,100
2   Juan    streetC 50  15      300
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `as_index=False` if you don't want the name as the index after the groupby operation.

2nd, there is no need for the lambda use `.agg(list)`

```
dfend0 = df0.groupby('name',as_index=False).agg(list)
```

then merge as usual.

```
df2 = pd.merge(df1,df0end,on='name')

   name  address  age      time      amount
0  John  streetA   30  [20, 10]  [100, 400]
1  Joan  streetB   40  [11, 18]  [200, 100]
2  Juan  streetC   50      [15]       [300]
```

Note, if you dont want lists use (not recommended as you lost the underlying datatype and end up with a string)

```
df0end = df0.astype(str).groupby('name',as_index=False).agg(','.join)

   name   time   amount
0  Joan  11,18  200,100
1  John  20,10  100,400
2  Juan     15      300

df2 = pd.merge(df1,df0end,on='name')

   name  address  age   time   amount
0  John  streetA   30  20,10  100,400
1  Joan  streetB   40  11,18  200,100
2  Juan  streetC   50     15      300
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['John','John','Joan','Joan','Juan'],
                   'time':[20,10,11,18, 15],
                   'amount':[100, 400, 200, 100, 300]})


   df=df.astype(str).groupby('name').agg({
    'time':lambda x : ','.join(x),
'amount':lambda x : ','.join(x)

})

print(df)
         time   amount
name                
Joan  11,18  200,100
John  20,10  100,400
Juan     15      300
```

at the end use `df=df.merge(df2,on='name')`